# Using object constructor in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop

As far as I understand, mostly we are defining objects in `state` like *object literal*. I haven't seen  *Object Constructor* way. [From my example](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-khorana-kj0fw), creating person by using constructor is neat and simplify for more complicated objects. My questions are;

1- Is using objects with `new` keyword bad practice? and Why

2- what is the proper approach? and Why

3- For objects that include too much nested variables how can we declare regularly?

Also I put the code,

```
class Obj {
    name = '';
    surname = '';
    age = 0;
    constructor(name,surname,age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }
    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
export default Obj;
```

```
import Person from './Object';
function App() {
  const [objs, setObjs] = React.useState({
    trialObj: new Person('trialName','trialSurname',25)
  })
  return (
    <div>{objs.trialObj.getName()}</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: 1) no, as long as the class methods don't mutate the class properties. Just don't see any benefit

Answer (score 0):

Note: New instance of an object is needed to re-render, it is a main concept of react

```
const UserMeta = () => {
 const [user, setUser] = useState(new User('name', 'age' ... 100 fields));

 return (
    <button onClick={() => setUser(new User('customName' ... 101 values via User.getSomething()))}>
      Update Name
    </button>
 )
}
```

Looks like an overhead when we can do

```
const UserMeta = () => {
 const [user, setUser] = useState(new User('name', 'age' ... 100 fields));

 return (
    <button onClick={() => setUser({ name: 'customName', ...user })}>
      Update Name
    </button>
 )
}
```

But in this case after button will be clicked our user will be an object with other stuff from class `User` :( such as getName() and etc...

This variant is better

```
const UserMeta = () => {
 const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: 'name', age: 'age' ... 100 fields));

 return (
    <button onClick={() => setUser({ name: 'Custom, ...user })}>
      Update Name
    </button>
 )
}
```

If you want to use models, pls, read [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) article. With TS you can prevent "forgotten properties" and etc.

F.E.

```
const UserMeta: React.FC = () => {
 const [user, setUser] = useState<UserModel>({ name: 'name', age: 'age' ... 100 fields));

 return (
    <button onClick={() => setUser({ name: 'customName', ...user })}>
      Update Name
    </button>
 )
}
```